# Cost function erratically varying

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

**Background**

I am designing a neural network solution for multiclass classification problem using tensorflow.The input data consist of 16 features and 6000 training examples to be read from csv file having 17 columns(16 features+1 label) and 6000 rows(training examples).I have decided to take 16 neurons as input layer 16 neurons in hidden layer and 16 neurons in output layer(as it is a 16 class classification).Here is my code for implementation-

```
import tensorflow as tf
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,16])
y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,16])
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial=tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.1,dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial=tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def read_from_csv(filename_queue):
    reader=tf.TextLineReader()
    key,value=reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults=[[1.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [1.],[1.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [1.],[1.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [1.],[1.],[1.]]
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17=tf.decode_csv(value,record_defaults=record_defaults)
    features = tf.pack([col1, col2, col3, col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16])
    labels=tf.pack([col17])
    return features,labels
def input_pipeline(filenames,batch_size,num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer([filenames],num_epochs=num_epochs,shuffle=True)
    features,labels=read_from_csv(filename_queue)
    min_after_dequeue=100
    capacity=300
    feature_batch,label_batch=tf.train.shuffle_batch([features,labels],batch_size=batch_size,capacity=capacity,min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return feature_batch,label_batch

x,y_=input_pipeline('csvnew1.csv',20,300)
#input layer
W_1=weight_variable([16,16])
b_1=bias_variable([16])
y_1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W_1)+b_1)

#hidden layer
W_2=weight_variable([16,16])
b_2=bias_variable([16])
y_2=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y_1,W_2)+b_2)


cross_entropy=tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_2),reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_2,1),tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
summary_cross=tf.scalar_summary('cost',cross_entropy)
summaries = tf.merge_all_summaries()

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Create a session for running operations in the Graph.
sess = tf.Session()
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('stats', sess.graph)


# Initialize the variables (like the epoch counter).
sess.run(init_op)
sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

count=0
try:
    while not coord.should_stop():

         #print("training....")
    #summary_writer.add_summary(sess.run(summaries), count)



    sess.run(train_step)
    if count in range(300,90000,300):
        print(sess.run(cross_entropy))
    count=count+1
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
finally:
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    coord.request_stop()

# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

**Problem**

The problem here is that as I print my cost function during training instead of generally decreasing trend it increases and decreases pretty randomly and erratically.I am pasting full code because it looks like implementation problem that I am unable to find.(varying learning rate is vain).

Edit:Decreasing learning rate to 10^-12 gives following costs(still erratic)

201.928,
173.078,
144.212,
97.6255,
133.125,
164.19,
208.571,
208.599,
188.594,
244.078,
237.414,
224.085,
224.1,
206.36,
217.457,
244.083,
246.309,
268.496,
248.517,
272.924,
228.551,
239.637,
301.759,....

I am printing cost after every 300 counts because 1 batch=20 examples,6000/20=300  counts for 1 epoch after which weights are updated.

Comment: anyone?........

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see your cost function increase when you use gradient descent, you should try **reducing the learning rate parameter**. Try repeatedly decreasing the learning rate by 1/10 until you see the loss decrease monotonically.